# BeautifulSoup is closing a the table after the first cell

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Good Day,

I am trying to use Python 2.7 / BeautifulSoup4 to parse a bunch of pages.  One of the pages is this one: http://www.eliteprospects.com/player.php?player=3664

My issue is that I am trying to get data out of the main table but soup is closing the table after the first cell.

So my code is this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")
t = soup.findAll('table', 'tableborder')
```

The length of t is 3, if I use html5lib or dont define the parser then t is zero.  I can't get lxml to install on my computer to try that.

So the main table, t[0] in the source code looks like this:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing=0 width=100% class="tableborder" >
   <tr class="trbackground" height="20">
   <td align="left"><font color="white"><strong>&nbsp;Season</strong></font></a></td>
   <td align="left"><font color="white"><strong>Team</strong></font></td>
   <td align="left"><font color="white"><strong>League</strong></font></td>
   <td align="right"><font color="white"><strong>GP</strong></font></td>
   <td align="right"><font color="white"><strong>G</strong></font></td>
...
```

t[1] and t[2] are different tables, and are able to pull the full table.  But t[0] looks like this:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tableborder" width="100%">
<tr class="trbackground" height="20">
<td align="left"><font color="white"><strong> Season</strong></font></td></tr></table>
```

It seems to be ending the table after the first cell.  I am not sure why it is doing this or how to stop it.  This same script literally worked on the same page a few months ago.  They might have updated their source code but I not sure what is causing the error.

Additionally trying to identify that table with different methods yields similar results, such as with:

```
t = soup.findAll('table', width='100%', cellspacing='0', cellpadding='0')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) and [let `BeautifulSoup` use it](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use):

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml")
>>> t = soup.findAll('table', 'tableborder')
>>> len(t)
4
>>> len(t[0].find_all('td'))
527
```

And, just to show the difference, what's happening with `html.parser`:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")
>>> t = soup.findAll('table', 'tableborder')
>>> len(t)
4
>>> len(t[0].find_all('td'))
1
```